# Convert the following codes(MIDIDDSP) to MIDI or wav

Tags: audio, python

I am attempting to use [MIDI DDSP](https://github.com/magenta/midi-ddsp) to synthesize midi file. However, I can't find how to convert these code lines to MIDI.

Here are the simple codes they've provided, and I didn't add anything, just followed what they've provided.

```py
from midi_ddsp import synthesize_midi, load_pretrained_model

midi_file = 'ode_to_joy.mid'
# Load pre-trained model
synthesis_generator, expression_generator = load_pretrained_model()
# Synthesize MIDI
output = synthesize_midi(synthesis_generator, expression_generator, midi_file)
# The synthesized audio
synthesized_audio = output['mix_audio']
synthesized_audio
```

`Synthesized_audio` returns as an array, and is neither a .wav nor midi file. Hope someone can tell me how to convert it to audio or midi.

Comment: it is "audio". It's audio samples. We've been there with your other question: these values *are* the audio. And since you start with MIDI data, you already have that.

Comment: so, all the data is there. It's not clear what your question is, but there's no more signal processing to be done here, so if anything, it would become a programming question.